# Why do multiple boost::io_services block main thread?

Tags: c++, boost

I have an application that needs to read from 7 serial ports. I have created a class that encapsulates the Serial port and opens up a boost::asio::serial_port and starts an asynchronous read operation. I am receiving all of my data however the io_service threads take up a lot of CPU time and slow down my main thread. Is there any way to stop the io_service thread from using so much CPU time?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] which demonstrates the issue

Comment: Your question title suggests you have multiple io::services.  That would be bad!  You only need one.

Comment: @ravenspoint I do. Each Serial port class has it's own io_service. Should I just make a static one and assign each port to it?

Comment: You should use just one.  Not sure what mean by static. For example I have an app that read two ports and writes to four ports, using one io_service.  The io-service looks after each port as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some pseudo code:

```
construct io_service
for each port
   open port
   start async read ( register read_handler_for_port )
run io_service

read_handler_for_port ()
   handle data
   start async read ( register read_handler_for_port )
```

Comment: Thank you this helped with my problem. It works fine with a few hiccups but  I'm figuring that out now.